# How to add an item after an item in My Places in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: google-earth

Here in My Places in Google Earth Pro we see we are about to add an item, e.g., folder *to* an item (Helicopter).

But how do we instead add an item *after* an item?

[image: Adding an item]

Answer (score 1):

**Repeat the process.**
[image]

After it is created you can drag items into the correct place.

Tip
copy an paste into notepad you will see the xml structure.

raw code example only

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>KmlFile</name>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl0</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin0">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin1</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl1</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin0">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin1">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin1">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl0">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl1">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>Helicopter</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>item1</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-95.00000000000003</longitude>
                <latitude>60.00000000000001</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>-5.565970692561154e-14</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>11001000</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin1</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>-94.99999999999999,60.00000000000001,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>item2</name>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>item3</name>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <coordinates>
                </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: OK. So we might have to scroll way far up off the screen to get to the top where My Places is.

Answer (score 1):

To add an item to the end/bottom of a folder, just select the folder and use the "Add" method you described.  This will also work if you select the top-level "My Places" folder. So if you want to add an item below the Helicopter folder (not in the Helicopter folder), just select its parent folder (My Places) first.